# Disable laptop touchpad on Wayland

Tags: touchpad, wayland, libinput

I need to disable the touchpad of my laptop. I am using Gnome **on Wayland**.

- `libinput` should provide this functionality, but apparently it doesn't.
- `xinput` doesn't work because I'm on Wayland.
- I think Gnome offered some switch to do so in the input settings, but it isn't there anymore (Gnome shell 3.34 — maybe this is an Xorg exclusive feature?).

Is it really asked too much if I want do disable an input device?

---

**Edit: `xinput` is NOT a solution!**

Its man page has a whole section on Wayland (emphasis mine):

> **XWAYLAND**
>
> Xwayland is an X server that uses a Wayland Compositor as backend.  Xwayland acts as translation layer between the X protocol and the Wayland protocol  but  does not have direct access to the hardware. The X Input Extension devices created by Xwayland ("xwayland-pointer", "xwayland-keyboard", etc.) map to the Wayland protocol devices, not to physical devices. These X Input Extension devices are **only visible to other X clients** connected to the same Xwayland process. Changing properties on Xwayland devices **only  affects the  behavior of those clients**. For example, **disabling an Xwayland device with xinput does not disable the device in Wayland-native applications**. Other changes may not have any effect at all. In most instances, using xinput with an Xwayland device is **indicative of a bug in a shell script** and xinput will print a warning. Use  the  Wayland Compositor's native device configuration methods instead.

**TL;DR**: If I disable the touchpad using `xinput`, it will still continue working as before, but XWayland applications won't see the cursor move anymore.

Comment: This helps? https://fazlearefin.blogspot.com/2014/08/disable-touchpad-using-keyboard-shortcut.html

Comment: As I wrote in the question, "xinput doesn't work because I'm on Wayland". From the xinput man page, section XWAYLAND: "For example, disabling an Xwayland device with xinput does not disable the device in Wayland-native applications."

Comment: Does `xinput list` work (it may still work under Wayland I believe) and show a touchpad (like "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" or similar? (You may have to install the `xinput` package.)

Comment: No it doesn't, but there is `xwayland-pointer:16` and `xwayland-relative-pointer:16`, among a few other similar entries (probably for mouse and graphics tablet, but I can't really tell them apart)

Comment: @piegames OK, I will write this in an answer so you can try it, please let me know below! You can also edit your question to include the full output of `xinput list` and we will have a look together.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Added the indicator link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, try if this dconf setting is of any use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing 'false'
```

It was stated with `false` while the name would imply `true`.

This setting should be for Xserver configurations:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'disabled'
```

Notebook also may disable the touchpad with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>;
you may try that.

If that doesn't work,
please add the output of `libinput-list-devices` to your question. 
You also may want to have a look
at the [Touchpad Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/131/touchpad-indicator/) GNOME Shell extension.

Comment: `lsusb` does not show my device. Apparently the touchpad is not connected on the USB bus, but as a Super I/O device.

Comment: Well, then it will be listed by `lspci` i guess?! Won't be of any problem. I will have a look, later.

Comment: Wow, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'disabled'` did the trick. I'm pretty sure that I tried similar gsettings commands before without any success.

Comment: If it works, accept the answer or give an error-report.

Answer (score 0):

This may work with `xinput` even if you are using Wayland.

Install the `xinput` package if necessary.  Then find out which is your device by typing

```
xinput list | grep -i touch
```

You may find a string like "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad".  Leave out the `grep` part if the list is empty to see whether you can find something else that sounds like touchpad.

Use this string (modify the next command as needed) and type

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0
```

You can re-enable the touchpad with a "1" instead of a "0" at the end.

Comment: Doesn't work: the cursor still moves around, but X applications don't see it moving anymore.

Comment: @piegames Too bad. It seemed to work for others on the Internet even with Wayland but perhaps something was/is different here.

Answer (score 0):

Other methods were not working for me on KDE Plasma, so I tried to disable the touchpad the naive way:

`ydotool key 530:1 530:0`

This command essentially sends KEY_TOUCHPAD_TOGGLE which request to switch touchpad on or off.

In order for this setup to work, the `ydotoold` daemon must be running in background (e.g. as a systemd service):

```
cat ~/.config/systemd/user/ydotoold.service
[Unit]
Description=Starts ydotoold service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=/opt/ydotool/ydotoold
ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
TimeoutSec=180

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Now it's possible to programmatically activate/deactivate touchpad, for example, in scrips or through KDE Connect.

Tested on ydotool version 1.0.4 from GitHub.